# SQLite query with 2 tables displays result 4 times

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

For a multi-language Quiz-Application I added a new table (Answer_Lv) to my database which contains values that have to be translated. In my case I want all answers to the first question with the id 1. Here I'm joining 2 Tables: Answer and Answer_Lv. The correct result should be 4 rows (4 possible answers) but I'm getting 16 rows.

This is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Answer, Answer_Lv
WHERE Answer.question_id = 1
AND Answer.question_id = Answer_Lv.question_id
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: how many records are there in each table for question_id = 1?

Comment: There are 4 records for question_id = 1

Comment: 4 in which table?

Comment: Answer and Answer_Lv have both 4 records for question_id. The _id column is the normal id for each record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looks of it, you need to join `_id` column too:

```
SELECT *
FROM Answer a, Answer_Lv b
WHERE a.question_id = 1
AND a.question_id = b.question_id
AND a._id = b._id;
```

Comment: @Deno Try this?

Comment: Yes, thank you. This works. But in the WHERE clause it has to be "a.question_id". By the way: do you think this is a good way to support multi-language? With a second table for values that have to be translated

Comment: Thanks. You should post that as a new question. There are many good people ready to help you.